# Autotools : how to set global compilation flag

Tags: c++, autotools, autoconf, flags, automake

I have a project with several sources directories :

```
src/A
   /B
   /C
```

In each, the Makefile.am contains

```
AM_CXXFLAGS = -fPIC -Wall -Wextra
```

How can avoid repeating this in each source folder ?

I tried to modifiy src/Makefile.am and the configure.in, but without success. I thought I could use AC_PROG_CXX to set the compilation flags globally but can't find much documentation on how to use those macro (do you have any pointer to such a documentation ?).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do several things:

(1) One solution is to include a common makefile fragment on all your `Makefile.am`s:

```
include $(top_srcdir)/common.mk
...
bin_PROGRAMS = foo
foo_SOURCES = ...
```

in that case you would write

```
AM_CXXFLAGS = -fpic -Wall -Wextra
```

to `common.mk` and in the future it will be easier to add more macros or rules to all `Makefile.am`s by just editing this file.

(2) Another solution would be to set these variables globally in your `configure.ac` (the name `configure.in` has been deprecated long ago), as in :

```
...
AC_SUBST([AM_CXXFLAGS], [-fpic -Wall -Wextra])
...
```

Then you don't even have to say anything in your `Makefile.am`s, they automatically inherit this global definition.  The drawback is that you can't opt-out easily (with the first solution it's easy to decide not to include `common.mk`) and the dependency is not really explicit to third-party people (when they read the `Makefile.am` they have no hint about where the flags may come from).

(3) A third solution would be to do as [orsogufo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15622/orsogufo) suggested: overwriting the user variable CXXFLAGS in `configure.ac`.  I would advise against it, because it defeats one of the features of the GNU Build System: users are allowed to override this variable at `make`-time.   For instance you may want to type

```
make CXXFLAGS='-O0 -ggdb'
```

when debugging a piece of code, and this will overwrite any definition of `CXXFLAGS` (but
not those in `AM_CXXFLAGS`).  To be honest, most projects fails to support this correctly because they play tricks with `CXXFLAGS`.

Finally, I should mention that `-fpic`, `-Wall`, and `-Werror` are not portable options.
Depending on the scope of your project you may want to add configure check for these ([gnulib](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/) recently acquired new macros to tests for warnings flags, and [libtool](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/) can be used to build shared libraries).

Comment: Using the include idiom in Makefile.am will make cause automake to output dependencies for Makefile and Makefile.in that eventually get back to the included file and the automake file.  So changing this will lead to updates later too.

Comment: It's actually very easy to opt out if you AC_SUBST the flags.  In Makefile.am, if you assign AM_CPPFLAGS, they override.  You can opt in by doing nothing, or by doing AM_CPPFLAGS = @AM_CPPFLAGS@ ..., or opt out by not putting @AM_CPPFLAGS@ in the assignment.

Comment: Warning flags does not belong in CPPFLAGS like you claim, since they are use by the compiler as opposed to the pre-processor.

Comment: Am I missing something, or doesn't the `AC_SUBST` need quotes `''` around multiple flags, to avoid getting a shell error while running `configure`?

Answer (score 0):

Use EXTRA_CFLAGS in configure.ac

For example for your case it would be this:

`EXTRA_CFLAGS=-fPIC -Wall -Wextra`