# How to tell AC_SUBST to not substitute variables in arguments?

Tags: c++, autotools, autoconf, automake, m4

I'm using autotools to build my project and I'd like to globally set AM_CPPFLAGS to -I$(top_srcdir)/include.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/325436/2592351 this answer helped me and I'm doing the "include $(top_srcdir)/include" hack and it works.

However I'd like to do the "AC_SUBST" way described there as it looks cleaner. The problem is when I add this to my configure.ac:

```
AC_SUBST([AM_CPPFLAGS], [-I$(top_srcdir)/include])
```

then $(top_srcdir) is expanded too soon and I get AM_CPPFLAGS = -I/include in subdir/Makefile{,.in}.

And I don't get how to escape it.

```
-I@top_srcdir@/include
-I\$(top_srcdir)/include
-I$$(top_srcdir)/include
```

all these failed for various reasons.

Please help. How should I write the AC_SUBST so $(top_srcdir) is not escaped before it gets to Makefile{,.in}? Or maybe I should use something other than AC_SUBST?

Comment: Not tested at all, but try `[-I@S|@@{:@top_srcdir@:}@/include]`.  https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Quadrigraphs.html#Quadrigraphs

Comment: Thank you @Zack but it gets substituted prematurely as well.

Comment: Drat.  Could you post the output of `grep AM_CPPFLAGS config.status configure`, please (after running configure, of course)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set `AM_CPPFLAGS` in your `configure.ac`. If  you find yourself repeating the same preamble in multiple `Makefile.am` you should be using [non-recursive automake](https://autotools.io/automake/nonrecursive.html).

But in this particular case, you should get away with it if you do

```
AM_CPPFLAGS='-I$(top_srcdir)/include'
AC_SUBST([AM_CPPFLAGS])
```

Because then the string is set quoted in the bash variable, and afterward expanded as a literal. Using `AC_SUBST` to set it up, it gets quoted by `""` which then causes `$(top_srcdir)` to be shell-expanded.

Comment: AC_SUBSTing AM_CPPFLAGS is okay to do.  Simply adding the single quotes in the invocation of AC_SUBST will also work: `AC_SUBST([AM_CPPFLAGS],['-I$(top_srcdir)/include'])`