# How do you set autotools default C++ compilation flags

Tags: c, autotools, flags, autoconf, automake

I am quite new with using autotools and I am still learning.

So, as stated in the title of my topic I would like to know how to set compilation flags.

I know there already has been a [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323790/autotools-how-to-set-global-compilation-flag) on this but it didn't solve my problem :

I used :

```
...
AC_SUBST([AM_CXXFLAGS], [-Wall -Werror])
...
```

but unfortunately, when using `./configure` I get:

```
...
./configure: line 3436: -Wall: command not found
...
```

and as a result it produces Makefiles but with no targets

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: In fact I haven't yet found a single project matching autotools features, so I cannot agree with the above comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The answer provided by Idav1s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25951837/539810) works for me as well because

```
AC_SUBST([FOO], [BAR QUUX])
```

expands to the following shell code:

```
FOO=BAR QUUX
```

which runs QUUX with the FOO environment variable set to BAR. In your case, this means `AM_CXXFLAGS` is set to `-Wall`, and `-Werror` is executed. Why you're seeing `-Wall` executed instead is unknown to me... For me, the error happened on line 2802:

```
configure: line 2802: error: -Werror not found
```

So I opened the `configure` script, and what I found was the `AM_CXXFLAGS=-Wall -Werror` on line 2802. Changing it to `['-Wall -Werror']` in configure.ac fixed things for me.

The Autotools build system is quite portable, and it makes cross-compilation easier than some build systems (e.g. Cmake requires a toolchain file with special variables set). I wouldn't suggest switching build systems just yet as a solution to such a simple problem.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

**configure.ac**

```
...
AC_SUBST([AM_CXXFLAGS], ["-Wall -Werror"])
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Set them in `Makefile.am` instead:

```
AM_CXXFLAGS = -Wall -Werror
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but is there absolutely no way of setting it in the `configure.ac` file ?